# Libgdx with Box2d in Android Studio jniisactive error

Tags: java, android, libgdx, java-native-interface, box2d

I am using android studio with Libgdx v1.6 and Box2d. I am developing a game which uses screens and, within those screens, stages. I have finished coding my game and I want, when the player dies, to transition from the `GameScreen` to the `GameOverScreen`. My `GameScreen`'s stage is a `GameStage` which extends stage. The game runs fine but when the player dies, and I execute game.setScreen(new GameOverScreen()); the game crashes and Android Studio gives the following error:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000066be70b0, pid=5016, tid=11188

JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b18) (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode windows-\amd64 compressed oops)
Problematic frame:
C  [gdx-box2d64.dll+0x270b0]

Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

An error report file with more information is saved as:

*Save location*

Compiled method (nm)   10173  910     n 0       com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body::jniIsActive (native)
 total in heap  [0x0000000002eea810,0x0000000002eeab80] = 880
 relocation     [0x0000000002eea930,0x0000000002eea978] = 72
 main code      [0x0000000002eea980,0x0000000002eeab78] = 504
 oops           [0x0000000002eeab78,0x0000000002eeab80] = 8
Compiled method (c1)   10173  909       3       com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body::isActive (9 bytes)
 total in heap  [0x0000000002ee9f10,0x0000000002eea280] = 880
 relocation     [0x0000000002eea030,0x0000000002eea068] = 56
 main code      [0x0000000002eea080,0x0000000002eea160] = 224
 stub code      [0x0000000002eea160,0x0000000002eea208] = 168
 oops           [0x0000000002eea208,0x0000000002eea210] = 8
 metadata       [0x0000000002eea210,0x0000000002eea220] = 16
 scopes data    [0x0000000002eea220,0x0000000002eea238] = 24
 scopes pcs     [0x0000000002eea238,0x0000000002eea278] = 64
 dependencies   [0x0000000002eea278,0x0000000002eea280] = 8

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
  http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
See problematic frame for where to report the bug.

AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed

Process finished with exit code 1
```

It is obvious that there is an issue with box2d. When the game transitions away from the current screen, the previous screen is `dispose()`d of. When I dispose my `GameScreen`, I do the following: (Bear in mind that the context of this extends Stage)

```
world.clearForces();
world.setContactListener(null);
Array<Body> bodies = new Array<Body>(world.getBodyCount());
world.getBodies(bodies);
for (Body body: bodies){
    world.destroyBody(body);
}
bodies.clear();
world.dispose();
renderer.dispose();
clear();
getBatch().dispose();
super.dispose();
```

I presume that the error comes when disposing of `world` (Which is an instance of `World`). In the source file for world, under `dispose()`, it has one line: `jniDispose()`. This clearly links to the `jniIsActive` in the error and The problematic frame is in C (Box2d is written in C).

What am I doing wrong? Is there a different way to dispose the stage? Do I not need to dispose it at all? (Bearing in mind it is likely that another `GameStage` will probably be created in the near future)

Comment: try `body.setActive(false)` before destroy them

Comment: @AlexandroSifuentesDíaz tried that, for every body, and still get the same error (bodyIsActive)